# Free automatic deployment systems?

Tags: windows, deployment, open-source

Are there any free systems for deploying new applications across a Windows network?

e.g. if I wanted to automatically install Silverlight to every PC?

(Assuming a Windows network of about 150 machines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Windows domain you should read up on using [Group Policy to install software](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738858(WS.10).aspx). Having said that, though, if the software isn't packaged in Windows Installer (MSI) format this becomes significantly harder. Using Group Policy [Startup Scripts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198642) to perform silent installations of non-MSI-based packages is certainly possible, but you need some scripting skills to pull that off.

You might also have a look at [wpkg](http://wpkg.org/). It sounds right up the alley of what you're looking for. There's a pretty strong community around it, and you can usually find "recipes" written by others for common installation needs (example: http://wpkg.org/Microsoft_Silverlight).

Personally, I go the route of Group Policy, either using MSI-based installs or custom Startup Scripts, but I've played around with wpkg and like what I see with it, too.

Comment: wpkg appears to be dead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wpkgexpress-support/TKQxwk3inLo

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [WPKG](http://wpkg.org). From official site:

`WPKG is an automated software deployment, upgrade and removal program for Windows.`
+
`WPKG is open source software.`

There are already many existing [silent installers](http://wpkg.org/Category:Silent_Installers) available (including [Microsoft Silverlight](http://wpkg.org/Microsoft_Silverlight)) and writing custom packages is [pretty easy](http://wpkg.org/Packages.xml).

PS: Update [Windows Script](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c717d943-7e4b-4622-86eb-95a22b832caa&displaylang=en) on Windows 2000/XP computers if needed, and (**CRITICAL**) test your packages well on all platforms (XP,2k,Vista,7) before you do massive deployments - [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) can be one tool for this.

PS1: Some [testimonials](http://wpkg.org/Testimonials) from satisfied users.

PS2: WPKG can also do:

- Windows Updates, but [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx) is the way to go
- Change registry settings etc., but Group Policy is the way to go (if you have AD)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have AD, why not GPOs or Windows Deployment Services?  Those are both included in the Server 2003/2008 software.

Answer (score 1):

We use WPKG (wpkg.org) -- an open-source deployment/upgrade/removal program for Windows.  Cheers

Comment: I've also used WPKG in places where WSUS wasn't an option.  It takes a bit to setup all the xml files but once it's all setup it's pretty easy to maintain and works well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck finding free ways to deploy general software. Windows components like Silverlight can be installed via WSUS server, which is free (And disk/memory intensive, in my opinion) and integrates with Active Directory to keep your systems up to date. It acts as a kind of local mirror for Windows Updates.

I have run into several "quirks" with it not necessarily upgrading your clients in a timely manner and I think the interface for getting accurate and up-to-date update information absolutely sucks, but it does help with bandwidth and keeping systems in your Windows network relatively up to date. And it's free from Microsoft.